# ACF Custom Fields, Custom Post Types and Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a front end using Understrap/Bootstrap and CMS system in Wordpress using ACF and custom posts. I am trying to integrate a carousel displaying product images and information taken from a custom post type.

The fields are pulling through but I have an issue with all the carousel-items being active which causes them to overlay each other.

I have seen similar issues when using an ACF repeater field but nothing using post types.

I know the solution is to add a php snippet with $num to control which slides are active but I can't work out where or how to add the code in the loop.

Code is below, any help, advice or relevant answers appreciated.  Thanks

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<?php $featured_posts = get_field('ski_category');

if( $featured_posts ): ?>   

<div class="carousel-inner">

<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

// Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
setup_postdata($post); ?> 


    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active; ?>">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 p-3">

                <img src="<?php the_field('equipment_image'); ?>">

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 p-3">

                <h3><?php the_field('skisnowboard_name'); ?></h3>

                <?php the_field('equipment_description'); ?>
                 
                 <small class="text-muted"><?php the_field('user_level'); ?></small>


            </div>

        </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>  

</div>

<?php 
// Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add counter ($i) and based on slide number - echo active class.

```php
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<?php $featured_posts = get_field('ski_category');

if( $featured_posts ): ?>   

<div class="carousel-inner">

<?php $i = 0; $active = ''; foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

if ( 1 == $i ) {
  $active = 'activeSlide';
}
// Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
setup_postdata($post); ?> 


    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo esc_attr( $active ); ?>">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 p-3">

                <img src="<?php the_field('equipment_image'); ?>">

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 p-3">

                <h3><?php the_field('skisnowboard_name'); ?></h3>

                <?php the_field('equipment_description'); ?>
                 
                 <small class="text-muted"><?php the_field('user_level'); ?></small>


            </div>

        </div>
</div>

<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>  

</div>

<?php 
// Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: please notice - I added active html class `$active = 'activeSlide';`, probably you need just simple `active`.. I don't know which plugin you are using and how exactly (literally) class should be named.

Comment: Thanks Ivan

Your reply made perfect sense. I just needed to tweak it slightly to make the first slide active.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer above gave me the solution.  The first slide needs to be active to implement the carousel correctly.  The code I've used is below incase it is of use to anyone else:

```
   <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<?php $featured_posts = get_field('ski_category');

if( $featured_posts ): ?>   

<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php $i = 0; $active = 'active'; foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

    if ( 1 == $i ) {
$active = '';
    }
```

// Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
setup_postdata($post); ?>

```
    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo esc_attr( $active ); ?>">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 p-3">

                <img src="<?php the_field('equipment_image'); ?>">

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 p-3">

                <h3><?php the_field('skisnowboard_name'); ?></h3>

                <?php the_field('equipment_description'); ?>
                 
                 <small class="text-muted"><?php the_field('user_level'); ?></small>


            </div>

        </div>
</div>

<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

</div>

<?php 
// Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```